# mongodb- accessing records from ids in list

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb as my backend. I have to store similar document ids in a list for each document. Here is a sample record in my collection.

```
{
   "_id": ObjectID("...."),
   "doc_name": "my_doc1",
   "doc_id": "doc_id_1",
   "similar_docs": ["doc_id_6", "doc_id_86", "doc_id_93"],
   "more_fields": "..."
}
```

This way I am keeping track of similar documents to each document.
Now I wish to have the complete json for all the similar documents to a given document. Right now I am implementing it using a for loop over the list of doc_id's making a request to database for each doc_id. Is there any subtle way to do this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a single query, something along these lines:

```
db.collection.find({_id: {$in: [doc_id1, doc_id2, ..]}});
```

But if you wanted a way to somehow "expand" those ids into documents when querying for parent document, then you can't do that. Unless you **store** full documents in that array (which can be expensive or impossible (if resulting document exceeds max document size)).